# error":"Unprocessable Entity","message":"Server could not parse JSON"

Tags: json, parsing, curl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hF79.png)I am running below curl code to verify a user in Sandox Zendesk environment but it is giving me error "Unprocessable Entity","message":"Server could not parse JSON". Could anyone advise what is issue here?

curl https://abccompany.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/create_or_update_many.json \ 
-d '{"users": [{"name": "User2", "email": "user2@testuser.com", "verified": true}]}' \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \ 
-v -u myemail@gmail.com:Password

I have attached the screenshot of the error. Also below are some of the details of the same error:

{"error":"Unprocessable Entity","message":"Server could not parse JSON"}* Connection #0 to host abccompany.zendesk.com left intact
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: /
* Could not resolve host: \
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: User2,/
* Could not resolve host: User2,
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: User2,
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: email:/
* Could not resolve host: email
* Closing connection 3

Comment: That looks like a command line, not a piece of Java code. Also, you've tagged this [javascript], which is quite different from [java]...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I ran the code in command line now after I saw your comment but it is still giving me error. I have updated the error details in my question. Could you pls advise what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Do single quotes work like that in command line? To test, save the JSON as a file (e. g. `request.json`) and use a reference to that: `curl ... -d @request.json`.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I am not sure if single quotes work as I am new to curl/json. Could you tell what code do I need to put in json file and also like when I run the curl statement what code changes I need to do so that the file can be accessed.

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Thanks but it is still not working. It is giving different error now as below:    {"error":"UnknownAttributeError","description":"Invalid attribute: missing users parameter"}

Comment: Well, the original error is fixed, JSON parses now. What is the proper way to verify a user in Zendesk is another question. I know almost nothing about Zendesk, but I'm pretty sure `create_or_update_many.json` is not a method to **verify** a user.

Answer (score 0):

What I mean is create a file in the current directory called `request.json` with the following content:

```
{"users": [{"name": "User2", "email": "user2@testuser.com", "verified": true}]}
```

And run the following command line:

```
curl https://abccompany.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/create_or_update_many.json -d @request.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -u myemail@gmail.com:Password
```

Substituting your own e-mail and password.